# Show Content On below single product with specific category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add some content to single products page in wooocommerce. But I don't know how to do it.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product','woo_after_product');

function woo_after_product() {
    if(is_product_category('mobile-covers')) {
    ?>
    <div class="specs-wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img class="spec-img" src="http://uperfect.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/transparentDiamond_1.png" alt="Product size and specs">
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <ul class="p-desc">
            <li>
                <p class="spec-title">1. Complete protection
                </p>
                <p class="spec-content">Impact-resistant, durable hard plastic case with an extremely slim profile, with raised front bezel for extra screen protection.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p class="spec-title">2. High quality printing
                </p>
                <p class="spec-content">Expect no peeling, chipping, or wearing off. 
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p class="spec-title">3. Free access to buttons
                </p>
                <p class="spec-content">Complete access to all standard buttons and ports, tailored for your device. 
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p class="spec-title">4. All side design
                </p>
                <p class="spec-content">Case covers 100% of the outer surface of the phone, precision moulded with no seams or sharp edges.
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>  

    <?php
    }
}
```

as i am applying is product category.
But my logic is that this content should be only shown to products with catgeory "Mobile Covers".
How will I do that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks reasonable to me. You're saying it doesn't work? Is your hook getting called, is the check not working, is the content going in the wrong place, something else?

Comment: i want to show content on single products not on category page.

Comment: OK. Do you mean that this content is appearing on the category page too and you don't want it to? Or the is_product_category check isn't working on the single products page? Maybe you should modify the single product page template instead rather than trying to do this with a hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the current post is in the `mobile-covers` category in this way:

```
if ( has_term('mobile-covers', 'product_cat') )
```

[In the documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_product_category.html), you can read about the `is_product_category ()` function that:

> Returns true when viewing a **product category**.

therefore, used on single product page always will return FALSE.